# Auth0/React getProfile not returning user information

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I am trying to retrieve a user's profile information using this tutorial here:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/02-user-profile

My scope looks like this:

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
 // ...
 scope: 'openid profile'
});
```

Here are the two functions inside my `Auth` file.

```
  getAccessToken() {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (!accessToken) {
      throw new Error('No Access Token Found');
    }

    return accessToken;
  }

  getProfile() {
    let accessToken = this.getAccessToken();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.auth0.client.userInfo(accessToken, (err, profile) => {
        console.log(profile);
        if (profile) {
          resolve(profile);
        } else if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

When I console log the profile I get this instead of the user's info.

```
{sub: "auth0|5aba531bbf06807d56cdb6c5"}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is just returning the fields for the scope openid. Where did you specify the scope?

Comment: Inside the `new auth0.WebAuth` object.

Comment: Inside of the `Auth` file as they say to in the tutorial.

Comment: It seems I just did not have any profileInfo for my account, I switched to a google account and it returned some profile information.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Change the scope in auth0 object to include profile:

```
scope: 'openid profile email'
```

Set an empty user profile object

```
  userProfile = {}
```

Then set the profile to the response from auth0.

```
  getAccessToken() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('access_token')) {
      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      return accessToken
    }
    else {
      console.log("No accessToken")
      return null
    }
   }

  getProfile() {
    let accessToken = this.getAccessToken();
    if(accessToken) {
      this.auth0.client.userInfo(accessToken, (err, profile) => {
        if (profile) {
          this.userProfile = { profile };
          console.log(this.userProfile)
         }
       });
     }
   }
```